# Spring MVC @modelattribute in proxied controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations, modelattribute

I have a controller which has an interface as proxy

```
@Controller
public class MyController implements IMyController{

    public FormBean getCommand(){
        return new FormBean();
    }

    public String onLoad(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res){
    }
}
```

The interface as follows:

```
public interface IMyController {

    @ModelAttribute("formBean")
    FormBean getCommand();

    @RequestMapping("/onload.do")
    String onLoad(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res);
}
```

Problem is, the getCommand() method doesn't get called anytime. I have also tried by moving the modelattribute annotation to the implementation class but to no avail.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public String onLoad(@ModelAttribute("formBean") FormBean form, HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) {       
   return "pageName";
}
```

Comment: Thanks,but this is not equivalent to the @modelattribute annotation.

Comment: How about now after the change?